# Import JSwing class into J Form tab

Tags: java, swing, jform

I am after some advice, I am quite new to Java, im using net beans. 
I am trying to get a J swing form into a J form tab, please can someone advise how I can achieve this.

Currently I have a Jform call cam.java this form has multiple tabs, I am trying to add a jswing class which is also another form called emailform.java into one of the tabs panel. I just cant work out how to do it.

Any help would be gratefully appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: It will be difficult to answer your question without a valid code sample. Please post your code, preferably as an [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org) that demonstrates your problem.

Comment: What do you mean by "a jswing class" ?

Comment: hi the jswing class the following [link](http://www.codeforge.com/read/15178/SendMail.java__html) i am trying to get that class into a tab onto my jform class